# Data limiting with a button in spotfire

Tags: bar-chart, visualization, ironpython, spotfire

im trying to change the data limiting expression on a bar chart in spotfire by pressing a button, using an ironpython script.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
for vis in Application.Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    if vis.Title == "BarChart1":
    vis.Data.WhereClauseExpression = "[Column1]=Test"
```

So in the above example im trying to change the filtering expression to show only the data that has "Test" in column1. 
The error im getting is the following:

> AttributeError: 'Visual' object has no attribute 'Data'

What does that exactly means and how can i fix it?

(I have not added any parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
for vis in Application.Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    if vis.Title == "BarChart1":
        visualContentObject = vis.As[Visualization]()
        visualContentObject.Data.WhereClauseExpression = '[Column1]=Test'
```

Also, I would recommend doing this as a parameter and not by title in case your title becomes dynamic.